# Delete double elements in Nested List

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, element

I have a nested python list called:

```
[[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]]]
```

In that list, I have every element doubled.

Example:

```
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]]
```

is the same as

```
[[[['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]]
```

How can I delete the double elements using list comprehension?
I've tried to convert the list into a set, but that does not work.

The desired output should be:

```
[[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
[[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]]]
```

Thanks

Comment: how did you come by this _censored_ piece of data?

Comment: how are `[ 'getting_hit_by_baseball_bat', 'gettin_a_million_dollar']` the same as `['gettin_a_million_dollar', 'getting_hit_by_baseball_bat']` the same? First one is money from suing, latter is a lottery win followed by a robbery taken place - kinda different

Comment: does the order of r,s,v,w inside the bigger list matter? means: `r,s,w,v!=r,s,v,w` right?

Comment: And lastely - where is the code _that does not work_ with wich you tried to solve this mess? _Why_ does it not work?

Comment: @PatrickArtner They are the same because I have physical properties, where the commutative law of maths is guilty ;)\
yes, the order inside matters.

Comment: there is most certainly a better way to organize this data with other structures, this is an absolute mess, I would suggest reworking whatever code created this muck

Comment: if you want to solve the problem by converting to sets and then convert back, you should first convert the nested list to nested tuples

Comment: But my question is now how to remove these double elements?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I've wrote it into the question ;)

Comment: Look above, I've edited :)

Comment: why is the desired output the same exact terrible format? how about when you have to perform the next step, you'll have to unnest again? this is honestly a terrible question with no attempt shown by you, I am voting to close this until more info is provided

Comment: @aws_apprentice Because I have 4 lists and I need to know, from which list, my characters come from.

Comment: @aws_apprentice There is no way of really knowing where the data came from. It is quite possible the OP has no control over what data he is given.

Comment: but he certainly has control over what happens next, putting it back in this same format is ridiculous

Comment: Yeah, if I will post my class here, which creates the data, it will be horrible for you to understand, what I want to do

Comment: What I can say, the indices are standing for density matrices which have a 2 body rank and that's, why I need them in one array, that I know for example
lambda^(pt)_(qu) is one irreducible 2-body density

Comment: @aws_apprentice
So what is your suggestion for a nice format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary with the flattened values in each sublist:

```
d = [[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], [[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], [[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], [[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], [[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], [[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], [[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], [[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]], [[[['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], [[[['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], [[[['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], [[[['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], [[[['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], [[[['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], [[[['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], [[[['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]]]
def flatten(_d):
   return [[c for [c] in _d[0][0]], [c for [c] in _d[0][1]]]

def match(a, b):
  return all(c == d for c, d in zip(sorted(a), sorted(b)))

_d = {i:flatten(a) for i, a in enumerate(d)}
result = [a for i, a in enumerate(d) if not any(match(_d[i], _d[c]) for c in range(i))]
```

Output:

```
[[[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['w']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['s'], ['t'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['v'], ['u']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['u']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['w']]]], 
 [[[['p'], ['s'], ['v'], ['w']], [['r'], ['q'], ['t'], ['u']]]]]
```

Comment: Thank you but my fault, I had one dimension too much is the following was fine:
    return [[c for [c] in _d[0]], [c for [c] in _d[1]]]